# run JavaScript without UIWebView

Tags: iphone

is it possible to run JavaScript in objective-c without using UIWebView ? i ask for this because i need to get the part of html data created by JavaScript when the web page loaded .the html source look like this

```
<table dir = "rtl .......">
<tbody>
<script src = "get.aspx?type=js&file=ajax&rev=3"......>
<script language = "JavaScript" src = "get.aspx?type=js&file=mc&rev=6"></script>
<script>..</script>
<tr>..</tr>
<tr>..</tr>
<tr>..</tr>
<tr>..</tr>
<tr>..</tr>
<tr>..</tr>
<tr>..</tr>
```

all < tr> after < script>..< /script> tag are created at runtime.i can't see them when i download the html source with NSURLConnection.hope some body help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible.  You'd have to implement your own Javascript interpreter.